# Mapreduce job: combiner without reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reducers, combiners

I noticed that if I set number of reducer to 0, the combiner won't work. Is it possible to use combiner without reducer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No it's not.  Even with a specified Reducer, combiners are not guaranteed to be used. So combiners are strictly optimizations that can be, but are not necessarily, called before Reducers.  Without a reducer these will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of the combiner is to 'combine' parts of mapper input so that the map outputs consume lesser network bandwidth when sent over to the reducer. Without the reducer, the whole point of using a combiner becomes moot. Hence, no, it is not possible.